# Vulkan tries to use Intel GPU by default

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, intel

Whenever I try to play a Vulkan game, I get a black screen because the game's trying to render to my Intel GPU (which isn't connected to any monitor). Using the launch option "VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json %command%" in Steam works, but I'd like to know if there's a way to use my Nvidia GPU by default.  I'd disable my Intel GPU but I likely will be connecting a monitor to it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the end of the file named `.profile` located in your home directory:

```
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES="/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json"
```

Comment: Hi there, can you please explain what this does and why it is needed. This will help users understand if they should follow your advice.

Comment: @Jeremy It will run "export VK_ICD_FILENAMES="/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json"" at the begining of session.